# How to interface UART servo? (LX-224HV)

Tags: uart, gpio, servo

I am trying to interface a RaspberryPi (2B) GPIO-UART to the this serial servo (Hiwonder LX-224HV), as a first step before to switch the Raspberry by an ARM MCU (STM32F407ZE on custom circuit).

The servo is supposed to follow a simple protocol, however, I am unable to manage any response from the servo (neither movement or UART response).

The documentation I found about the servo is limited (Note that this is another servo model, but according to vendor, their controller is compatible with both, consequently, I assume some compatibility):

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b3v81sb9nwir16q/AADXOwhdw7KLq5t5UM8ND3kwa/LX-15D%20Bus%20Servo?dl=0&subfolder_nav_tracking=1

**Testing signal:**

For testing purpose, I am sending the following message through command line:

```
#Some ports initialization here
echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio24/value # disable rx
echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/value # enable dx
echo -n -e "\x55\x55\xfe\x04\x0e\x01\xee" > /dev/ttyAMA0; sleep 0.001;
echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/value # enable dx
echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio24/value # disable rx
```

The message is made of:

- 0x55 0x55: transmission start tag.
- 0xFE: Id of the target servo, 254 means broadcast
- 0x04: Length of the block, including this length to
  ending checksum
- 0x0E: 14 is Read_ID, asking the servo for it ID.
- 0x01: default Id (not used?)
- 0xEE: Checksum ~(254+4+14+1) =  ~(17) = 238

**The circuit is set as follow:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNU503.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note, I added a resistor to avoid burning any component in case of short-cut, It also allows to see variations in the signal if the servo tries to send any data.

The connection to the servo is done as follow:

- 0-5V to signal, high impedance most of the time.
- 12V to the VDD
- 0V to the GND

The breadboard look like this:

[image]

**The result signal:**

The resulting signal at the signal pin of the servo-motor is as follow:

[image]

There is no significant signal after this, which I interpret as the servo not responding for any reason.

**The question:**

Is there any obvious missing element in this approach? or ultimately, how to interface with this servo?

I found many others servos with similar interface, so I believe this could help further users..

Comment: Note: I also tried other types of messages (rotate), without more success

Comment: AH, the datasheet looks detailed enough. Let me read it tomorrow and see if I can help. One weird thing is that the serial bus seems ***daisy chained***, not the ordinary point to point, one bus for one device/servo type, (Of course not PWM controlled). Reference: (1) LC224-HC Servo: https://www.hiwonder.hk/products/hiwonder-lx-224-hv-three-connectors-bus-servo. See you tomorrow. Cheers.

Comment: I think the following document is more helpful: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b3v81sb9nwir16q/AADXOwhdw7KLq5t5UM8ND3kwa/LX-15D%20Bus%20Servo?dl=0&preview=LewanSoul+Bus+Servo+Communication+Protocol.pdf&subfolder_nav_tracking=1 Thank you

Comment: Ah yes, your drop box doc of course is more helpful. Earlier I have difficulty opening your drop box. This time is smooth. See you tomorrow.

Comment: Multidrop serial on a bidirectional line is a quite normal thing; let's please address the actual issue of the question not unfamiliarity with the concept.  Some things to check would be that the baud rate is correctly set, that the device expects these voltage levels and this inversion sense (vs any of the RSxxx standards which would be opposite sense and possibly higher voltage), that the device address is correct, and that the transmit word is getting completely clocked out before the driver is disabled.  Consider probing both sides of that series resistor...

Comment: @Adrian Maire, Good morning. The docs in your drop boxed are very good and comprehensive. So I google and learned many more things I didn't expect to know. Questions: (1) ***Have you bought the LX-244 offline controller/tester**? I am drafting a shopping list, including the offline controller. You might like to comment on my incomplete answer, or brainstorming me counter suggestions. Cheers.

Comment: (1) I did not bought the controller/tester board initially because I did not expected this to be so difficult, however considering the current situation, I did bough one yesterday which should arrive in some 1-2months.
(2) Yes, the baud-rate is set to the expected frequency (excepting any error from my part). 
(3) the device address should be correct, as I am using broadcast.
(4) The word is getting completely clocked out before the driver is disabled: Checked.
(5) Voltages and levels: you see the wave from the oscilloscope, but I can't ensure anything more.

Comment: Ah, just now I searched your drop boxes with many goodies and found the LeWaSoul Bus tutorial with a circuit on using HC126, and I then understand why it is there and what is it used for. Previously I wrongly thought that it was your design and so did not pay any any attention to it. I have not read the complete LeWanSoul thing but I guess the HC126 is for implementing ***Simplex protocol***. where UART can only go one direction, either send or receive at one time, but not send and receive at the same time. Now the HC126 is used to control the send or receive operation. / to continue, ...

Comment: So I guess the following is what is going on: (1) Rpi set send mode, then say "AT" to LX-244HV servo, with its ID. (To make things simple, let us assume that there is only one servo). (2) Then Rpi set to receive mode, and wait servo to reply. (2) So when testing, you need to set send or receive mode by ***disabling and enabling the correct HC126 channels***". (3) One more complication is that I think the circuit is for 5V Arduino. /to continue, ...

Comment: So if you are using Rpi, you need to ***Shift 3V3 logic signal to 5V***. Only if you have wired this level shifter first, then later you can set send of receive mode. Comments and counter suggestions welcome.Cheers.

Comment: The 74HC126 does the job for the 3.3V to 5V conversion, and the resistor divider for the reception (100k & 68K). Also enTx and EnRx enable and disable the gates.

Comment: Thank your for pointing out my careless mistake. I did quickly read the datasheet and make sure you can only set HC126 Vcc to 5V, hoping HC126 are 5V tolerant, but that is risky because of latching up danger. I once thought about using HC03 and CD4040, or 2 x TSX0102 each with enable/disable. I must confess that I did not read your bash commands carefully, so you do set send before sending "AT", then set recv mode before receiving "OK"? Any way, my toys not yet arrived. When they arrive, I will first use the Win10 tool to play with LX-244, then try my python "say Hello" program. Cheers.

Comment: Ah, I missed this part "the resistor divider for the reception 100k & 68K". So I have no more worries.  Ah, one more thing, if you still have your Arduino lying around, you can just run the Arduino demo programs. Ah, supper time. See you Monday or Tuesday.

Comment: And a short question. Have you tried (1) put LX-224 aside, just test the HC126 wiring, (2) Enable both buffers, and see if sending out a test byte, say "0x55" will loop back, eg. scope read the reach back?

Comment: I cannot loop-back, as the driver is either enabled for reading, or for writing (not both at the same time). However with the oscilloscope, I can detect any signal in both directions, even if colliding (and prior to the driver gate) (result in the image). I see no signal from the servo unfortunately, it is probably just ignoring fully my input. I will make further tries when the controller will arrive.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, pointing out my ignorance on the half duplex circuit using HC126. I agree that if you use a scope to look at the input terminal of the servo, of course you are pretty sure that the servo is getting the serial string 0x55 etc. I also agree that if you don't see clashing signals after the input to server, there is little chance that the servo is returning anything. / to continue ...

Comment: I might try my dual TSX0102 up shifter to see if I can do the loop back. Perhaps I am wrong to think that enabling both HC126 can then loop back, but perhaps it it sort of short circuiting TxD to RxD. But perhaps TSX0102/04 is different, because their input/output are open drain, therefore can be connect together, but only 80% sure. / to continue, ...

Comment: Now 2 pieces of bad news. (1) My toys, including the offline servo checker, arrived yesterday. I thought I could easily check if a servo work, moving it and monitoring it temperature, over/under voltage etc. But to my surprise, I could not do that, because that is for ANOTHER BOARD called controller or something. (2) The 15 yuan board I said is a must buy perhaps joke to your and me, because I found two chips on board: HC126 and CH430. But I don't need them, because I am using my own TSX0102 and UART/TTL. There are also many misleading or wrong info in my deleted answer. / to continue, ...

Comment: My old answer mentioned about another half duplex uart servo, but I mixed up with the Korean servo Dynamexal which is very expensive, and I did not have a chance to play with it. Now this LX-224 is perhaps a good chance for poor hobbyists like me to have a taste of the future servos. Just thinking aloud, sorry for the typos. Cheers.

Comment: ***Good News!*** I installed BusLinker V2.4 in Chinese Win 10 and tried it with LX-824HV and it worked immediately. No need to do any adjustment. Ch340 serial driver is auto detected. By just clicking I could select port, open/close motor, select servo mode, adjust position. Then display window shows position, voltage, and temperature. I don't need online controller now. This offline tester is more than enough for me. Installation of BusLinker take two minutes, and the complete test takes another three minutes. I finished everything in only 5 minutes! Cheers. https://i.imgur.com/xlTD9Cg.jpeg.

Comment: Good! Could you record the bus with any simple operation? (e.g. move or request ID)

Comment: Ah, "Moving servo to a particular position" is a bit hard to repeat using python, and might take me 30 minutes. "Setting servo to motor mode and turning continuously is dead easy - just click, click,click, and drag and drop, all done in 15 seconds. That is why I said earlier that the 15 yuan (US$2) offline test board is a must buy. :) Cheers. PS - It would be nice if you can read my scope screen capture and verify if bus linker is indeed sending a motor turn command, and servo is replying something like: "OK, OK, so I am turning".

Comment: So I will wait for you to check out my scope displays. In the mean time I am moving on to design the rpi-level-shifter-and_simplex_uart. Basically I am doing the following (1) Shift 3v3 logical signal to 5V0. (2) designing enable/disable signals for the UART directional control buffer, what you are using HX126 for. Now I am thinking of using TSX0102 to replacing HC126.

Comment: I have drafted v0.1 of the TSX0104 based simplex UART cct to replace the HC126. One thing I am not sure is whether to use two diodes to direct the signal to/from LX-224 too TSX0102 outputs before shorting together, or let the TSX0102's no sensor auto direction sense control to auto do all things in one go. Comments and counter suggestions welcome.

Comment: One brainstorming idea is this. When Rpi sends a text string, the sent string will immediately loop back, but Rpi can just ignore this loopback string. After waiting for some time for the LX-224 to settle down and send back the reply string, then Rpi will at this time reads the message. At this time, Rpi is not sending anything, so the sent back LX-224 string will not clutter with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time researching the topic together @tlfong01 and me(@adrian_maire), we managed to get the servo working through the Raspberry Pi (from now: RPI) without the need of the driver board.

For this purpose, several problems has been solved:

1. Converting voltage level from 3.3V (RPI) to 5V (servo bus)
2. Implementing the different UART messages for the RPI
3. Converting full-duplex UART to half-duplex UART

**Converting voltage level from 3.3V to 5V**

Even if this could be a sub-optimal solution, considering that the `74HC126D` allows level conversion, two of them has been used to manage both problems: enabling and disabling of Tx/Rx and level conversion at the same time.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpSnN3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Implementing the different UART messages for the RPI**

A project has been created (GPL3) to any of you to use it.

https://github.com/Escain/HiwonderRPI

(The code is unfortunately too large to include here.)

**Converting full-duplex UART to half-duplex UART**

For the conversion of full-duplex to half-duplex UART, the servo relay on the enabling and disabling of the full-duplex TX (transmission) and RX (reception) line:

- When RPI transmit, it enable TX and disable RX
- When RPI don't transmit, it disable TX and enable RX so the servo can answer.

The servo start answering UART request some 0.1ms after reception, this is below the OS scheduling time of any modern operating system, including Raspian. In consequence the first attempt to drive en-TX and en-RX by software was totally unsuccessful.

To solve this issue, the en-TX is implemented by hardware, through a retriggering monostate 555 timer of around 0.1 ms.
The en-RX is just the negation of en-TX.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhsZ47m.png)</sup>

**Connecting all together:**

1. Tx is connected to the RPI GPIO 14
2. Rx is connected to the RPI GPIO 15
3. enTx from both circuits are connected together
4. Servo S is connected to the signal of the servo
5. Gnd and VCC (3.3V, 5V and 9V) are connected to the circuits and to the servo. (This servo is HV and thus, support up to 12V, but others Hiwonver servos can NOT manage 12V, be careful).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

*How can Rpi4B talk to duplex BUS UART servo LX-224HV?*

---

***Answer***

*Part B - Rpi4B UART to LX-224HV Simplex Serial Ciruit Design V0.1*

[image: lx-224 simplex cct design]

Next step is to let Rpi to send commands to LX-224 and see if is replies back anything.  The OP reports nothing comes back.  So I will repeat his commands and see if I have better luck.

The Op is sending the following commands.  I think I better read the servo command manual to make sure the commands are OK and will not fry the servo.

```
0x55 0x55: transmission start tag.

0xFE: Id of the target servo, 254 means broadcast

0x04: Length of the block, including this length to ending checksum

0x0E: 14 is Read_ID, asking the servo for it ID.

0x01: default Id (not used?)

0xEE: Checksum ~(254+4+14+1) = ~(17) = 238
```

---

*Part A - LX224HX Troubleshooting Using BusLink V2.4*

*I am using the HiWonder Bus Linker V2.4 to display the send receive signals when the LX-224 UART/Bus servo is set to motor mode and move continuously at about 700 rpm.*

---

[image: lx224 motor test 2]

---

[image: motor signal 1]

---

[image: motor signal 2]

---

[image: motor signal 3]

---

***References***

(1) [LewanSoul Bus Servo Communication Protocol](https://github.com/RoboticsBrno/Robotic-arm/raw/master/Hardware/Servo-LX16-A/Lewansoul%20Bus%20Servo%20Communication%20Protocol.pdf)

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - The OP's test setup*

[image: The OP's test setup]

---

*Appendix B - HiWonder LX-224 BusServoController setup*

[image: lx-224 controller]

---

*Appendix C - HiWonder LX-224 BusLink V2.4 Setup*

---

[image]

---

*Appendix D - TSX0104 Level Shifter for implementing LX224 Simplex UART/BUS Servo Bidirectional Control*

[image: tsx0102 1]

*/ to continue, ...*

---

*Not yet completed answer.  Stay tuned, ...*

Comment: Hello @tlfong01, thanks you for your great research :-)   Looking at your oscilloscope output, it does not resemble to any of the message that I have in the documentation. My initial conclusion is that the protocol explained is either wrong or has been significantly changed. It would be interesting to have more samples of communication to reverse-engineer the protocol. The on of your picture is probably about querying the temperature/voltage or position.

Comment: Ah, I see. But I am not surprised, because I am using the Win10 Bus Servo Terminal GUI command to turn the motor non stop so I can easily us a scope to display something. There are other things that cause trouble: (1) I am using BusLink version 2.6, but I read the AliExpress and Amazon are selling old versions. So there might be outdated commands. The other thing is that I found HiWonder keeps saying that they cannot help users to develop software, because HiWonder is asking LeWanSoul to develop the LeWanSoul simplex uart servo protocol. So LeWanSoul might not the have motor turning commands.

Comment: Ah, supper time, so see you late this evening or tomorrow. Cheers.

Comment: In your circuit, I suggest you to add the pull-up resistor and also some 0.5k in-serie resistor between the bus and the servo. This will avoid any error to burn to quickly your devices.

Comment: Ah that is a good advice I carelessly forgot . I usually use 330R or 470R series resistor to limit the motor current. I am also using a very small 220VAc to 12VDC 1A (yes, 1A only) PSU then step down to LM2596 12V to 5V to supply the LX-224. So I think LX-224 should at most take 1A or a bit more, hopefully no to fry anything. And also that is why I am using the less expensive servo, not the most expensive one, just in case, ... Cheers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112589/discussion-between-tlfong01-and-adrian-maire).